# How can I run Apple Hardware Test with a firmware password set?

Tags: apple-hardware-test, firmware-password

I have a firmware password set using the Firmware Password Utility.

When I hold <kbd>D</kbd> immediately after power-on to start Apple Hardware Test, nothing happens.  My computer boots normally.

How can I start Apple Hardware Test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your firmware password must be disabled to start Apple Hardware Test.  To do this:

1. Either boot into OS X Recovery (hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while powering on) and select Firmware Password Utility from the menu, or follow [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117084/21050).
2. Select "Turn Off Firmware Password...": [image: Firmware Password Utility main window]
3. Enter your firmware password to disable it: [image: Dialog to enter old firmware password]
4. Select "Quit Firmware Password Utility": [image: Firmware Password Utility main window after password disabled]
5. Restart your Mac and attempt to launch Apple Hardware Test again with <kbd>D</kbd>.